# Как сделать автоматический запуск программы на python'e после перезапуска компьютера?

Tags: python

У меня есть программа (выводит просто пустое окно), скомпилировал в исполняемый файл с помощью pyinstaller

вот смотрите, предположим сейчас оно открыто, я перезапущу пк и при повторном включении компьютера, нужно будет заново кликать по нему чтобы открыть

а как сделать так, чтобы если оно было активно, то при перезапуске пк, автоматически открывалось?
код в программе такой, если нужно:

```
import tkinter
import time
time.sleep(10)
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='blue', height=300, width=600)
canvas.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: В автозагрузку добавь